# Query optimization challenge - Is it possible to tweak this linq query

Tags: c#, sql, performance, linq, query-optimization

I am in to a perf excercise and I am wondering if there is any chance to improve this, just by the way I query for this info rather than attempting to do any DB schema or data changes.

The below **query takes around 200 ms to execute**. I know I am ambitious but the challenge is is there a way to bring down. I am ready to employ ADO.NET or use a SP or use sql query but cannot do any data change. Also, **the EmpTable has around 20 million rows**.
It selects 1 record matching the paramid.

Any one think this is still possible to optimize further ?

```
Log.Time()
            using (MyDataContext db = MyDataContext.GetContext())
            {
                db.ObjectTrackingEnabled = false;
                var _Query = from t in db.EmpTable
                             where t.id == paramId
                             select t;

                 if (!_Query.Any())
                    return null;
            }
            Log.Time()  -- 200 ms approx
```

Comment: Have you already profiled the query?  There isn't much to change with the code, so you'll have to look into adding an appropriate index on the table.

Comment: Load data into a hashtable once, and then search for paramId in memory. I don't think you can bring down query execution time much.

Comment: If performance is that much of an issue I would avoid using linq because the sql it generates can be obfuscated at times.

Comment: @48klocs the index is there already, we compare paramId with the primary key.

Comment: Profile it. How long does the actual query take to return? If that returns in much less than 200ms you could maybe see if [precompiling the query](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896297.aspx) helps at all (not sure it would for something so simple)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is some small overhead using linq (but you are micro optimizing anyway). You can try and execute the raw SQL instead and see if you get any performance change.

```
using (MyDataContext db = MyDataContext.GetContext())
{
   var exists = db.ExecuteQuery<bool>(@"
       SELECT CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT NULL FROM EmpTable where t.id == {0}) 
       THEN CAST(1 As bit) 
       ELSE CAST(0 As bit) END", paramId);
   if(exists)
      return null;
}
```

Also is `GetContext()` doing anything more than creating the context?

Comment: GetContext was taking a bit of time where I optimized.. marking this as answer since it helped...

Answer (score 1):

Your query looks very simple and you won't be able to improve on it much.

The first place I would check would be to see if you could add an index on the table that was optimized for this query to improve performance.

Get a query execution plan for the query you are running and look for any problem areas. This really seems like a problem that could be best solved with database tuning.